# Small script involving grep to pass on for the next command

Tags: bash, grep

My network card's name keeps alternating names between `enp4s0` and `enp3s0` after startup. In addition, it also starts `DOWN`. Everytime I login I have to do this, manually:

```
ip link   # it outputs the names
sudo ip link set enpXs0 up
sudo dhcpcd
```

So I tried to make a small script to be run with `.xinitrc`. This is what I came up with:

```
#!/bin/bash
CARD=ip link | grep -o enp[4\|5]s0
echo ${CARD}   # check
sudo ip link set ${CARD} up
sudo dhcpcd
```

but it doesn't work: `link: missing operand`. I thought I have to use quotes when assining `CARD`, it's not so. Neither is using full path names (`/usr/bin/ip`). How to set up the `CARD` variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
CARD=`ip link | grep -o enp[4\|5]s0` #here in card need save result
echo ${CARD}   # check
sudo ip link set ${CARD} up
sudo dhcpcd
```

Command substitution.

Answer (score 2):

Command substitution:

```
#!/bin/bash
CARD=$(ip link | grep -o enp[4\|5]s0) #here in card need save result
echo ${CARD}   # check
sudo ip link set ${CARD} up
sudo dhcpcd
```

[Backtick are not recommended while using command substitution.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082)

Comment: It does look like it should be the preferred way, but my case is a very simple one, so it works either way. Upvoted, though.